# HTML Portal - Failed to Execute 'activate' on 'HTMLPortalElement' Portal Element is not associated with a portal context

Tags: html, portal, lit-element, lit-html

I'm trying to create a HTMLPortalElement with Lit-Element, but when i'm ready to activate() the Portal i get this Error in Web Dev Console :

DOMException: Failed to execute 'activate' on 'HTMLPortalElement': The HTMLPortalElement is not associated with a portal context.

```
class WikiPortal extends LitElement {
  static get properties() { return {
     _portalSrc: String
  }};

 constructor() {
   super();
   this._portalSrc = 'https://wicg.github.io/portals/';
 }

render() {  return html`
      <portal src="${this._portalSrc}" @click="${this._portalClickHandler}">
      </portal>`;
}

_portalClickHandler() {
   this.shadowRoot.querySelector('portal').activate();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before answering I just want to mention that portal is an experimental element and is only available in Chrome Canary after activating it by visiting chrome://flags/#enable-portals.

There seems to be an issue with the creation of the portal element within a template/shadowDOM. The following is a workaround that worked for me. It is basically creating the portal element programmatically in the main DOM and appending it as a child to the custom element.  Note I added a test button within the component so I could see something to click.

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';

class TestElement extends LitElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._portalSrc = 'https://wicg.github.io/portals/';
  }

  render() {
    const template = html`<button type="button" @click="${this._portalClickHandler}">TEST</button>`; 
    return template;
  }
  _portalClickHandler() {
    var node = document.createElement("portal");
    node.src = this._portalSrc;
    document.querySelector('test-element').appendChild(node);
    console.log(document.querySelector('portal').src);
    document.querySelector('portal').activate();
 }

}

customElements.define('test-element', TestElement);
```

Comment: Seems portal can be activated only from the main document context!